I'm making a 2D board game on Godot and I need to get a signal from the child class - Player in the parent class - Game when it presses a button
I also need this to do private things, for example, pop-up windows that only the player sees, a table of players, where the player will always see himself first from left to right in the table, so that it would be easier for him to navigate the interface, that everyone has a “Roll” button ", but the one whose turn has not yet come cannot press,
only the one who is currently walking can press, that is, private states of buttons or tables or something else, that each player had his own interface in one game, but also so that the player in his interface could press the button and this signal would go to the parent class - Game
I’m not that good at the engine yet, so I don’t understand how to implement something like this, what should I do, please help me, if you know tutorials that can help me, documentations or anything like that, please give me a link

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
